# How to pull data from CATSone API with Authentication Token?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am completely new to coding. I am trying to build a dashboard in Klipfolio. I am using a CATSone API to pull data from CATSone to Klipfolio. However, I can only get 100 rows a time, which means I would have to pull data 2600 times.

I am now trying to build a script to get data from the API through Google Script Editor. However, since I have no experience in this, I am just trying stuff. I watched some videos, also from Ben Collins. The basis is simple, and I get what he is doing.

However, I have a problem with putting the API key.

```
    var API_KEY = 'key'

    function callCATSone(){

//Call the CATSone API for all candidate list
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.catsone.nl/v3/candidates");
Logger.log(response.getContentText());                                 

// URL and params for the API
var url = 'https://api.catsone.nl/v3/candidates';

 var params = {
 'method': 'GET',
 'muteHttpExceptions': true,
'headers': {
'Authorization': 'key ' + apikey
}
};

// call the API
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var data = response.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(data);
}
```

In the end, I would like to transfer all candidate list data to my sheets. Therefore, I call on the API with Authorization key. After that, I will manipulate the data, but that's for later. The first problem I now encounter, is this fail code:

> 'Verzoek voor https://api.catsone.nl/v3/candidates is mislukt. Foutcode: 401. Ingekorte serverreactie: {"message":"Invalid credentials."} (Gebruik de optie muteHttpExceptions om de volledige reactie te onderzoeken.) (regel 6, bestand 'Code')'.

I expect to get a list of all data from CATSone into my sheets.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Two changes should fix the credentials error:

Authorization header should be `Authorization: 'Token ' + yourApiKey` instead of `'key '`, see the v3 API documentation https://docs.catsone.com/api/v3/#authentication.

API key in your case is stored in a global variable `API_KEY`, you should reference it exactly like that, not as an `apikey` (unless there is a typo in your sample or some missing code): `Authorization : 'Token ' + API_KEY`.

Btw, it should probably set either a `Content-Type` header or a `contentType` parameter for `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` method call to `application/json` as `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` request content type defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you plan to continue working with APIs, it would be beneficial to read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your quick response. I tried adding the Authorization: 'Token ' + API_KEY variant like you told me to. However, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Hi Rick! Try adding the header like this `Authorization: 'Token <'+API_KEY+'>'` - initially, I interpreted signs as variable signifiers, if this does not do the trick, please, check if your subdomain is registered in .nl zone.

Comment: Rick, I looked through your code again, one question - is your first `UrlFetchApp` call commented out or deleted in your actual code? It seems like you make request twice - once without authorization and only then with (but as the first call does not have `muteHttpExceptions` param set, it fails with an error).
If so, please, disregard the previous comment and try the initial solution after commenting out / deleting the first request.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thanks for the quick answers.

I added the Authorization: 'Token ' + API_KEY like you told me to. I also changed the var response to UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params) and set the var params: 'method': 'GET'; 'muteHttpExceptions': true, 'header': { ' Authorization' : 'Token ' + API_KEY } };

I now get data, so it seems that it is working. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi Rick - great, glad everything works fine! As a best practice, always ensure that you included the `muteHttpExceptions` as a parameter to a `UrlFetchApp` call - this eases debugging process a bit :)